# Delete directory based on date

Tags: unix, date

I am writing zsh script in which I have to get the date of 90th previous day from current date i.e I have to subtract 90 days from current date. Then I have to check the folders which have different dates as their names. I have to compare the directory date with the subtracted date and if the result is greater than the subtracted date, I have to delete the directory.

For example:

Let us say the current_date = 20131130 (yyyymmdd)

subtracted_date=current_date - 90 days

lets say there is a folder 20130621

Now this folder name should be compare with the subtracted date. If greater than subtracted_date then i have to delete the directory.

Comment: For practical purposes you may also be interested in 3 months rather than 90 days. That would be fairly trivial.

Comment: But every month will not have 30 days. And its a client specification that the folder gets deleted exactly after 90 days.

Comment: Look at the name of the directory (there are no "folders" on a computer) and compute the epoch time of midnight on that day.  Add 90 * 24 * 3600 (ignore daylight savings offsets).  Compare to the current time.  Delete as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `date` command to find the date 90 days earlier to the current one.  The following script should give you a list of directories that need to be deleted:

```
del=$(date --date="90 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
for i in `find . -type d -name "2*"`; do
  (($del > $(basename $i))) && echo "delete $i" || echo "dont delete $i"
done
```

To perform the actual deletion of directories, you can replace the third line with the following:

```
  (($del > $(basename $i)))  && rm -rf $i
```

For example, if your current directory contains the following folders:

```
$ ls -1F
20120102/
20130104/
20130302/
20130402/
20130502/
20130602/
20130702/
```

Executing the above script would tell:

```
$ bash cleanup
delete ./20130302
delete ./20130104
delete ./20120102
delete ./20130402
dont delete ./20130702
dont delete ./20130502
dont delete ./20130602
```

Comment: Hi.... There is a folder with name 20130717. Now its prompting me to delete this folder also.

Comment: What does `date --date="90 days ago" +%Y%m%d` return on your system?

Comment: this is the result : 20130501

Comment: Are you using `bash` to execute the script?

Comment: yes... I am using bash. I am executing this script you gave in bash for testing but actually it should be executed in zsh.

Comment: this is the result when im running this:

`delete ./Archive/20130121`

`delete ./Archive/20130528`

`delete ./Archive/20130808`

`delete ./Archive/20130829`

`delete ./Archive/20131216`

`delete ./Archive/20120202`

`delete ./Archive/20120424`

`delete ./Archive/20130717`

Comment: The edit above should work.  The script assumed that you're executing the script from the location containing the directories to be deleted.

Comment: No... The script is not present in the location in which the directories are to be deleted. The script is in the path `/ntzrws/Data/Krg` and the directories to be deleted are under the directory `/ntzrws/Data/Krg/Archive`

Comment: The modified script should work.  Line 3 in the script has been changed.

Answer (score 19):

```
find path -type d -ctime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

should find all directories older than 90 days and use rm -rf on them

Be careful with that command though you will probably want to test it first with this

```
find path -type d -ctime +90 -exec echo {} \;
```

in order to keep certain folders consider `-mtime` instead of `-ctime` and touch the folder every so often

replace `path` above with the actual path you want to scan and delete

explanation

`find` is the command

`path` is the root directory you want to scan

`-type d` means look for directories only

`-ctime +90` means created time older than 90 days

`-exec rm -rf {} \;` means remove recursively and force delete of the items which were found

`-mtime` is modified time

The second command will list out all folder which will be deleted so is much safer to run while you are testing

Comment: Hi...

can you explain me the command? I mean the flags and their uses? I am actually new to unix

Comment: The comparison is to be based on the directory name rather than ctime.  Perhaps they are equivalent in this case, and perhaps ctime is actually more appropriate than the name, but perhaps not.

Comment: Can the folders be deleted based on the folder name? but not on the time of creation? This is for testing purpose. I have created some folders with names 20120304, 20130624, 20120718 and so on. These folders are created just now. So I want to delete based on folder names rather than the creation time.

Comment: use `touch -m (directory) (timestamp)` to modify the modified time changing the bracketed parts or touch -mt YYMMDDhhmm for a time in that format, check the man pages for more info

Comment: The folder names its self are the dates... 20120304, 20130624, 20120718 are not the modified dates of the folder, but the names of the folders

Comment: yes but in the real use of the application not just the test, They are the real dates correct ?

Comment: Yes they are real dates. What if someone opens the folder which is older than 90 days and do some modifications? wont the creation time change?

Comment: Only if they change that folder not the items in it. also its looking for created time rather than modified

Comment: Hi, how can this command be modified to delete directories that were created 30 days further back from 90 days to the current date? E.g cur_date - 20201107, 90 days back - 20200809, all directories to be deleted that were created between - 20200709 - 20200809. Thanks

Comment: multiple mtimes eg   `find -mtime +30 -mtime -100`  is older than 30 days, younger than 100 days, so anything between the two should appear there

Answer (score 4):

List directories before delete

```
find . -type d -ctime +60  -ls
```

List files before delete

```
find . -type f -ctime +60  -ls
```

Delete directories in current directory

```
 find . -type d -ctime +60 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Delete files in current directory

```
  find . -type f -ctime +60 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can also use the following command to delete all files in the current directory by date .*

[jamshi@cpanel ~]$ rm -rf `ls -l | grep 'Jul 19 15:32' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f9`